# React Native - Can't modify text in TextInput onChangeText callback on Android

Tags: react-native

Because of a well-documented issue in React Native, autoCapitalize for TextInput doesn't work correctly on Android. I tried to get around this by manually capitalizing the text in the onChangeText() callback:

```
onchgtext(newval)
{
  this.s8 = newval.toUpperCase();
  this.forceUpdate();
}

render()
{
   ...
   <TextInput value={ this.s8 } 
      onChangeText={ (newval) => { this.onchgtext(newval) } } 
      ...
   />
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, modifying the text causes the TextInput to not work correctly: *alternate* keystrokes cause the entire previous text to be duplicated, but only if the keystroke was lowercase.

So, entering `1234` results in `1234` showing up; entering `ABCD` results in `ABCD` showing up; but entering `abcd` results in `AABCAABCD`.

Any ideas why this happens, and how to work around it? Note that using `onChange` rather than `onChangeText` results in the same behavior.

Comment: have solved this issue?  Actually, I am facing the same issue, in my case number, capital letter, small letter anything didn't update the TextInput.

Comment: Umair, your issue seems different. In my case, the callbacks are being called just fine, but things get screwy when I modify the text inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this, using state?

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Text' };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({ text: text.toUpperCase() });
          }}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same result. I believe this is an issue inside TextInput itself; nothing to do with setState vs forceUpdate.

Comment: I tested this in an iOS Simulator, are you using android or iOS?

Comment: Android, thanks... I did mention it in the first sentence of the description but I've just added it to the title as well.